# Looping a batch file command a certain amount of times

Tags: batch-file

I have researched this. I have searched this place for a solution but I am keep finding weird long lines of code which I do not believe are necessary. 
I have trying to have a batch file loop my command 5 times.

```
    :loop
    start Node_B7
    goto loop %5%
```

This is the line of code I want it to start Node_B7 5 times. I have tried

```
    :loop
    start Node_B7
    goto loop
```

and it works although it does it an infinite amount of times. I am new to coding so sorry if this is a simple question. I know with VBS you can loop a certain amount of times so I am sure you can do this with batch files. Please don't tell me to just use VBS because I don't want to use VBS. The other commands I have inside this batch file excluding the loop do not work in VBS.

Comment: Either use a counter and check it's value `Set /a cnt+=1` and `if %cnt% lss 6 goto :loop` or use `for /l %%i in (1,1,5) Do start Node_B7`

Comment: Use a counter variable. First initialize it outside the loop `set counter=0`, then at the top of you loop `set counter+=1`, then `if %counter% equ 5 goto :EOF`.

Comment: @Annonymous, you should accept Squashman's answer, it's the correct one.

Answer (score 2):

A simple `FOR` command and use the `/L` option.

```
FOR /L %%G IN (1,1,5) DO start Node_B7
```

Comment: Thank you this helps a lot. I am also wondering while on it, can you loop a command inside a batch file a certain amount of times using the similar line of code?

Answer (score 2):

`help goto` and `help set` will get you a long way:

```
@echo off
set counter=0
:loop
if %counter% equ 5 goto :EOF
set /a counter+=1
echo %counter%
goto loop
```

Squashman's loop is better.

Comment: @squahman, count them, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4. that's five iterations. There's three things that are hard to get right in programming; naming things, and avoiding off-by-one errors ;)

Comment: The OP was looking for something like a "similar line of code". I thought I'd show an alternative. Personally, I gave @Squashman my vote. But whoever gave me an up-vote, thanks.